# css clearfix not working as expected

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I have a simple dl / dt / dd list,
it is narrow so some columns are double or triple liners, so I need to clear each line to make it look good, but I can't make the clearfix work, here's the code:

```
<dl>
  <dt>first column:</dt><dd class="clearfix">second column</dd>
  <dt>FIRST COLUMN:</dt><dd class="clearfix">SECOND COLUMN</dd>
  <dt>first column:</dt><dd class="clearfix">second column</dd>
</dl>

dl {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #555555;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
dd {
  float: left;
  width: 74%;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-table; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

and here's the fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7a0pgoef/

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `to make it look good`? Define *"good"* please.

Comment: good means - I want three separate (not overlapping) rows

Comment: It's not very clear what you're needing, but first thing you need to understand about this method of clearing floats is that it works on container blocks.  What you're trying to do (as far as I can tell) is use an column to clear a float.  If that's the case, it's on the wrong one (needs to be the first column) and you need to use `clear:left` (or `both`).  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/3s0kzwby/

Comment: thanks ! that's what I wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want each `<dt>` starts from a new line, you should give `clear` property to the `<dt>` itself in order to `clear` the floats from its `left` side.

```css
dl {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    clear: left;
}
dd {
    float: left;
    width: 74%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>first column:</dt><dd>second column</dd>
  <dt>FIRST COLUMN:</dt><dd>SECOND COLUMN</dd>
  <dt>first column:</dt><dd>second column</dd>
</dl>
```

---

`::after` is often used to append a pseudo-child element — whose clears the floats — into the parent element containing floats.

But in this particular instance, it doesn't help as `<dl>` elements cannot contain anything other than `<dt>` and `<dd>`. In other words, adding another wrapper around the pair of `<dt>`/`<dd>` is not allowed/valid.

Comment: great !!! thanks ! that's what I wanted to achieve :) I have tried many things but somehow not this, shame on me

Comment: @Picard No worries :-)